# Clearing the cache in rails without deleting everything else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, redis

I am using redis for the cache store in rails

Doing `Rails.cache.clear` will indeed clear the cache, but essentially remove everything else in Redis.

Is there a way to expire all the cache keys without completely removing everything else in redis?

Comment: Can't you configure your cache to use different redis database?

Comment: I can, and probably should, but I wonder if there is a way to clear just the cached items and not the entire db...

Comment: I'm not sure, but probably not. How do Rails know which keys are used by cache and which are used by another program?

Comment: Would be nice of rails to prepend something infront of the keys for quick access..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you know the keys already, you can go like this

```
# delete a single key
Rails.cache.delete(:key)

# delete many keys
Rails.cache.delete_if {|k, v| k =~ 'key' }
```

actually the Rails.cache keys are just a {} Hash , so you can go with any kind of ruby.hash methods.(hopefully im not wrong)

Comment: eventually thats what I did `Rails.cache.delete_if {|k, v| k.start_with?('views')}`